# Convert a string in the format dd-mm-yyyy into a date in angular 4

Tags: angular, date-formatting

How to convert a string in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` into a date object in angular 4 expression.

Example:

```
<h2>Test date : {{testDate | date :'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</h2>
```

If `testDate = '2005/01/21'` then date pipe is working fine.
But for `testDate = '21-01-2005'` , it showing invalid date.